# Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4:, Angular 4 and above

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My npm version is 5.6.0, I am trying to create angular 4/6 project(angular-cli) by using the command `ng new`. But, I get the error `The term 'ng' is not recognized`.

So, I try to install `angular-cli` by using `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Log

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.1.1
updated 1 package in 18.954s
```

But, I still get error => `The term 'ng' is not recognized`.
I am not sure, it might be related with is related with [event-steam's backdoor](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/a0kxmw/i_dont_know_what_to_say_backdoor_in_popular/)

Comment: Can you try `npm run ng -v` command

Comment: @veben when i run your commend, I get `6.4.1` after  I update npm like (`npm i -g npm@latest`)'

Comment: Make sure the **ng.cmd** file is present in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm` and this folder is in your Env Path var

Comment: I don't have `ng.cmd` file, because of I get error when I install `npm install -g @angular/cli` like my question.